# How to create coordinate system and locate points in R?

Tags: r, coordinates

How can I create quadrant I (+,+) of coordinate system in R and add points in it?

Comment: Do you mean a data frame? Thats really easy.

Comment: I mean asomething like this as visual: https://www.mathplanet.com/education/pre-algebra/introducing-algebra/coordinate-system-and-ordered-pairs

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean just a standard plot as this one:

```
points_plot<-data.frame(x=c(3,7,8),y=c(9,2,6))

plot(points_plot,pch=20)
```

[image]